# why migrations add will create empty migrations file?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I use Entity Framework Core 3.I have created new `Present` File

**Present.cs**

```
public class Present
{
    [Key]
    public string PresentedId { get; set; }
    public string ReagentId { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName ="smalldatetime")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool Paid { get; set; }
    public double ShareAmount { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ReagentId")]
    public virtual AppUser Reagent { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PresentedId")]
    public virtual AppUser Presented { get; set; }
}
```

my `DBContext`

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, IdentityRole, string>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    ///...
    public virtual DbSet<Present> Presents { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        ///...
        builder.Entity<Present>()
            .Property(e => e.Date)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getutcdate()");

        builder.Entity<AppUser>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Reagent)
            .WithOne(e => e.Presented);

        builder.Entity<AppUser>()
       .HasMany(e => e.Presents)
       .WithOne(e => e.Reagent)
       .HasForeignKey(e => e.ReagentId)
       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
}
```

I have added a migration

```
dotnet ef migrations add addedPresent ///this was successfull,and was not empty for first time
dotnet ef database update             /// this was with error
```

But when I wanted to update database I had a error that should remove Cascad.In database it not created new table(`Present`) and not add new row in `Migrations table` so,I deleted last migrations and  I changed  `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);` to `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);`
then I added new Migrations .But my problem is that it will create empty migrations file,And I don't know how solve this problem?

```
public partial class addpresent : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
    }
    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I used below command for removing migrations

```
dotnet ef migrations remove --force
```

and it executed with error but it removed the migration file(addPresent.cs)

> dotnet ef migrations remove --force
>   info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
>         Entity Framework Core 3.0.0 initialized 'AppDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
>   Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>   SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]');
>   info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20100]
>         Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>         SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]');
>   Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>   SELECT [MigrationId], [ProductVersion]
>   FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory]
>   ORDER BY [MigrationId];
>   info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20100]
>         Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>         SELECT [MigrationId], [ProductVersion]
>         FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory]
>         ORDER BY [MigrationId];
>   Removing migration '20191124071753_addPresent'.
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.CSharpHelper.Literal(String value)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpSnapshotGenerator.GeneratePropertyAnnotations(IProperty property, IndentedStringBuilder stringBuilder)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpSnapshotGenerator.GenerateProperty(String builderName, IProperty property, IndentedStringBuilder stringBuilder)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpSnapshotGenerator.GenerateProperties(String builderName, IEnumerable`1 properties, IndentedStringBuilder stringBuilder)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpSnapshotGenerator.GenerateEntityType(String builderName, IEntityType entityType, IndentedStringBuilder stringBuilder)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpSnapshotGenerator.GenerateEntityTypes(String builderName, IReadOnlyList`1 entityTypes, IndentedStringBuilder stringBuilder)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpSnapshotGenerator.Generate(String builderName, IModel model, IndentedStringBuilder stringBuilder)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationsGenerator.GenerateSnapshot(String modelSnapshotNamespace, Type contextType, String modelSnapshotName, IModel model)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.RemoveMigration(String projectDir, String rootNamespace, Boolean force, String language)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.RemoveMigration(String contextType, Boolean force)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.RemoveMigrationImpl(String contextType, Boolean force)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.RemoveMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I added New Migrations but it will still empty file

```
dotnet ef migrations add addPresent
```

**Edit 2:**

Now I added a table `Conversation` (for test) and I added migrations and it works ,and with

```
dotnet ef database update
```

It added table to database.but There is not `Present` table in database.I don't know how it detect that I added `Conversation` but not detect that I added `Present` .Now What should I do?

Comment: you should have removed the last migration after the error. see https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-migration.aspx

Comment: Try by adding -Force to the migration command

Comment: @Badri I used `--force` but it will create empty file still

Comment: After add addPresent you have to execute remove **twice** to remove addPresent and the addedPresent migration. The mirgrations are calculated on a model cache and the cache is currently at the old addedPresent migration which you have to remove too. Removing the migration class is not enough and will lead to this